# Proving existence of periodic solutions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

As answered in:

[Prove that $0$ is the only $2\pi$-periodic solution of $\ddot{x}+3x+x^3=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703953/prove-that-0-is-the-only-2-pi-periodic-solution-of-ddotx3xx3-0)

by user Empy2 in comments, to prove that a differential equation has periodic solutions, you must:

Find an $f(x,y)$ for which $f(x,\dot{x})=c$ is constant

Convert that to $\dot{x}=g(x)$

The period is $t=\int \frac{dx}{g(x)}$

If this is true, how can it be proved?

Thanks

Comment: $\ddot x\dot x+3x\dot x+x^3\dot x = 0$ and after integration $\frac 12\dot x^2+\frac 32 x^2+\frac 14x^4 = c$ after that $dt = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c-\frac 32 x^2-\frac 14x^4}}$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get periodic solutions it is sufficient to find the energy function $H(x,\dot x)=\frac12\dot x^2+G(x)$ with $G(0)=0$, with a square root $g(x)$ of $2G(x)=g(x)^2$ that is strictly monotonous on some interval $[-q,q]$. Then select $C=\min(G(p),G(-p))$ and conclude that all level curves $H(x,v)=c < C$ are bounded, thus closed. As $(x,v)=(0,0)$ is the only stationary point, on any level curve the tangents are non-zero, so after finite time the full level curve gets traversed. This gives a periodic solution.

In formulas, in the current example one gets $g(x)=x\sqrt{3+\frac12x^2}$, which is strictly monotonous, unbounded and smooth.

On a level set $2H(x,v)=2c=r^2$ the points $(g(x),v)$ follow a circle of radius $r$. Using polar coordinates for the circle,
$$
g(x)=r\cos(\phi), ~~ \dot x=v=r\sin(\phi)
\\~\\
g'(x)\dot x=-r\sin(\phi)\dot\phi
\\~\\
g'(x)=-\dot\phi
$$
Thus $\dot\phi=-g'(g^{-1}(r\cos\phi))$ is always negative.

Comment: Thanks for the aclaration, very kind.